# Java ASM Tree API: How to pretttyprint AbstractInstructionNode?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Is there any easy way to do this? I see a bunch of ways to use MethodVisitors and what not to print out entire class files, but all I need to do is print out a single instruction, hopefully in a nice way.

I've already found the OPCODES table to print out the opcode name, but is there any provided way to prettyprint the contents too?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have some random AbstractInsnNode:

```
AbstractInsnNode insnNode = new JumpInsnNode(Opcodes.IFLT, new LabelNode(new Label()));
```

then you can pretty-print it like this:

```
/* Create a "printer" that renders text versions of instructions */
Printer printer = new Textifier();
TraceMethodVisitor methodPrinter = new TraceMethodVisitor(printer);

/* render the instruction as a string and add it to printer's internal buffer */
insnNode.accept(methodPrinter);

/* convert printer's internal buffer to string and clear the buffer (so we can reuse it later) */
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
printer.print(new PrintWriter(sw));
printer.getText().clear();
String insnNodeAsString = sw.toString();

/* print the string out */
System.out.print(insnNodeAsString);
```

In this example insnNodeAsString will be:

```
"    IFLT L0\n"
```

i.e. it includes a line feed at the end.

We could wrap all this to a nice utility class:

```
public class InsnPrinter {
  private static final Printer printer = new Textifier();
  private static final TraceMethodVisitor methodPrinter = new TraceMethodVisitor(printer);

  public static String prettyprint(AbsractInsnNode insnNode) {
    insnNode.accept(methodPrinter);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    printer.print(new PrintWriter(sw));
    printer.getText().clear();
    return sw.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres no ASM function to prettyprint a methods bytecode. You will have to iterate through the instructions and print the ones you want to.